# Liquibase: how to run programmatically only those changesets which haven't been applied yet?

Tags: java, liquibase

I try to update existing DB with luquibase Java API in this way:

```
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance()
    .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation( 
        new JdbcConnection( connection ) 
    );
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase( 
    "db.changelog.xml", 
    new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), 
    database 
);
liquibase.update( "" );
```

But it tries to apply all change sets  including those which have been already applied earlier.  What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks correct, my guess is that you have a different classpath than when you ran it before. Liquibase identifies each changeset with an id+author+filepath combination, so if you are currently referencing db.changelog.xml as "db.changelog.xml" but previously used "output/db.changelog.xml" or "com/example/db.changelog.xml" it will see it as different.

If you "select * from databasechangelog" you will see what is stored as the path for each changeSet.

Comment: Yes, you guessed, Nathan. The problem was caused by filepath of changesets. In my case I need to apply db migrations on many already existing databases, so I have to ignore filepath. I solved it with custom implementation of ChangeSetFilter.